# Unable to upload file from Elastic Beanstalk to s3 due to access denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::spmgr/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowEBSService",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::823510892997:role/service-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::spmgr",
                "arn:aws:s3:::spmgr/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

On attempting to upload file from my elastic beanstalk worker instance, I get Access denied error.
(Though note that the same code on my local dev machine is able to successfully upload the file)
So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` is for EB service itself. For your application you have to provide role associated with your [Elastic Beanstalk instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html). You have to check what role your EB instances is
using.